# Alguien puede ayudarme con este error?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola llevo varios días intentando instalar cx_Freeze para convertir archivos python con extensión .py a ejecutables, pero cada vez que intento instalarlo me sale este error, no tengo idea porque, incluso ya he probado con distintas versiones de python, pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error. Si alguien sabe algo por favor responda. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Saludos es recomendable que agregues los comandos realizados por consola y el error que genera para darte una mejor respuesta, tambien especifica la version de Windows, gracias.

Comment: Bien, el comando que agregue fue: "pip install cx_Freeze". El error es el siguiente: error: "file 'C:\Users\JOSUEP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hp754dvz\cx-Freeze\cxfreeze-postinstall' does not exist". Mi versión de Windows es el 10 Home. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si no recuerdo mal, para instalar cx_Freeze necesitas instalar mediante Wheel. Quizás esto pueda ayudarte.

Para ello lo instalas mediante `pip install wheel`

Después te vas a esta dirección: `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze` y descargas la versión que quieras.

Aquí tienes un tutorial para instalar mediante Wheels:

`https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo!

Comment: @JosuePujols Si solucionó el problema, marca la respuesta como solución par que la gente que pueda tener el mismo fallo pueda solucionarlo.